# Mac OS unable to run .Jar file

Tags: java, macos, jar

So I've been writing this little code, and it works -- but I have to type in the whole `Computer;~ User$ java MyProject` and change the path every time, so I decided to stick it in a `.jar` file (so I could just run it on a double click). I am an Intellij user on running macos. I created the file, `File/Project Structure/artifacts/+/myMain` etc and now have a `.jar` file sitting on my desktop. When I run the jar inside of Intellij, or run the jar using

`java -jar /Users/Me/Desktop/MyProject/out/artifacts/MyProject_jar/MyProject.jar`, it works fine.

However, when I:

- *Run it from the terminal with `java -jar MyProject.jar` I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile MyProject.jar`*
  **^^Resolved** - using the **`chmod 755 MyProject.jar`** command, see comment for further details
- Or run it on right click with Jar launcher I get `The Java JAR file "MyProject.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error messages.` There are no error messages in the console.

And before anyone says it, I have Java 13 and the project is running on Java 13 -- it's the default that my computer has, and has been updated automatically ever since installation.

How would I be able to launch this file, and what could be stopping it from doing so?

Comment: what are the permissions of the jar file?  I believe that the jar file must be executable to enable it to be launched.  For the command line, try specifying the path, as in ```java -jar ./MyProject.jar```

Comment: @Fubar awesome, thanks for the response. Specifying the path worked. What do you mean by permissions though? And any clue how to make it executable?

Comment: @Fubar this worked exactly as you said it would, thank you very much - but the error on running with Jar Launcher still happens. Any idea why? Also, if you do figure it out, change that comment to an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terminal, do an

`ls -l MyProject.jar`

You'll see something like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 youruser yourgroup 1024 Apr 24 15:41 MyProject.jar
```

The -rw-r--r-- part is the file permissions where an "r" means readable, "w" means writable, and an "x" would mean executable, but as you can see there isn't one there. Without going into the long explanation, use the chmod command to make the file executable by doing

```
chmod 755 MyProject.jar
```

Afterwards, use the same ls command and you should see -rwxr-xr-x in the permissions field.  The file is now executable (by anyone) and should launch if you click in in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

If your program has no GUI but requires console input, you should run it from the terminal instead of double clicking it. When you double click the `MyProject.jar` file, you actually launch it through jar launcher. The jar launcher will pass the files to the JVM. However, since you are not launching it from the terminal, the JVM does not know which terminal to use, so the program might not be properly executed.